# Opencart closed login

Tags: php, opencart

I want to create an opencart webshop where customerts can see the content if they are logged in, otherwise redirect to a login page. I want to write it into the code somewhere, without any extension. I am really new in opencart.

Answer (score 1):

Please add following code on catalog/controller/common/header.php inside `index()` function

```
 if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
       if (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] != 'account/login') {  

           $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
       }
    }
```

If you want to enable both register and login, then following:

```
if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
       if (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || ($this->request->get['route'] != 'account/login' && $this->request->get['route'] != 'account/register')) {  

           $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
       }
    }
```

Comment: This will actually redirect continually, since the header is used on the login page too

Answer (score 0):

```
You need add below code

    if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) { //content code here
    }else{ $data['content']=''}

add above code on controller and enclose content so that only login user will be able to see that content.
and add link "login to view content" and use anchor tag to 
login page 
if($content=''){
//redirect code
}
```